# How to install docker, docker-compose on a server with no internet?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a server (Linux) with no access to Internet (required) I can SSH to that server to transfer file from my local to that server.

Now I need to install Docker and docker-compose on that server. I wonder is there any install file so I can transfer to that server and run the installation or not.

Moreover, I can not run install docker image on the Docker as well. Is there anyway to load from file instead of downloading the image from the internet.

Comment: You can find a binary with "which" - so if you want to know where the binary file for docker-compose is located, you can run "which docker-compose" in your terminal, and copy the binary via ssh to your server.

Comment: As for images, you can use docker load and docker save to save docker images as tar files, and load them with docker load